# force FireFox to use background-position-y using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, background-position

Does anybody know a little JavaScript that allows background-position-y(and background-position-x) being displayed correctly in Firefox?
that would save alot of stuff in the CSS.

Comment: What on earth are you talking about?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Can you be more clear about the specific problem you're having?

Comment: You might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask first. Try to improve this question and you will probably get more constructive answers.

Answer (score 1):

`background-position-x` and `background-position-y` are Internet-Explorer-specific properties. While they are admittedly extremely obvious and should be implemented by all browsers, Firefox tends to be stupid that way (such as not supporting MP3 despite it being the most-used format of sound ever...)

So to answer your question, no, there is not. You just have to use `background-position`. It's not that big of an issue, surely?

Comment: But well, that would make things much easier. I have got a bar with icons benath my header and on hover the Position of the Background changes, so that the icon "glows". And if that's not possible I need to make an entry for every single icon in my css.